# Recursive java method and xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, iterator

Hi I have a recursive method in Java used to parse my XML. I want to set a namespace for elements in a certain level of the XML. Tried setting a counter but it is not working. Can anyone help me?

Xml file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <LoginResponse>
         <Response>
            <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
            <ResponseDescription>Request processed successfully</ResponseDescription>
         </Response>
         <SessionKey>12345a</SessionKey>
         <Service>false</Service>
      </LoginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this response, I want to add namespace to the elements in the `ResponseCode` level.

Java code snippet:

```
    int level = 0;
    public void invokeBusinessLogic(Response response) throws Exception
    {   
        Iterator i = response.getFirstElement().getChildElements();//response.getFirstElement() is LoginResponse from the xml
        correctNamespace(i);
    }

    private void correctNamespace(Iterator i) {
        level++;

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            OMElement element = (OMElement) i.next();
            Iterator ii = element.getChildElements();
            element.setNamespace(null);
            if (level == 2)
            {
                element1.declareNamespace(URI, XMLNS);
            }
            correctNamespace(ii);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM needs to be [name space aware](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)).